# Symfony 2.0 adding multiple entries

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, crud

Is there a way to add multiple entries in symfony to database? I use ORM Doctrine and for example i want to create dynamic form:

```
Main form (Dish type):
  Name
  Description
  Prep time
  Variants (Variant type):
   [
       Add new variant: name (Add more, Delete)
   ]
```

With javascript support for adding multiple variants at once. For now i have default CRUD generated objects with ManyToOne connection between **Dish** and **Variant** therefore I don't think I need to include that easy piece of code :)

I can create javascript but how to get form from the browser? Is there any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using form collection. See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) cookbook entry.